# Entity Framework Many to Many query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

I want to write a simple query, but there are some problems.
I have 2 tables M to N:

Users -> Events.

I want to get all users of a specific event (get this event by eventId).

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsersByEventId(int eventId)
{
    IQueryable<User> query = this.Context.Users.AsQueryable();

    return query.Where(x => x.Events.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EventId == eventId)); ??
}
```

Something is missing and I dont know what, can someone help me? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (adding your models would help), I think you want `Any`

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsersByEventId(int eventId)
{
      return Context.Users
                    .Where(u => u.Events.Any(e => e.EventId == eventId));
}
```

This should return all users who have any event matching the given id.

Note: If you set up your relationships correctly, you should be able to get this directly from the Event.

```
public class Event
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

So then, you'd get the Event by id and access it's user collection.

```
var evt = repo.GetEventById(id);
var users = evt.Users;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do that in your Event model itself. AFAIK you are using `Event`, `User` and `EventUsers` tables which is standard stuff for many2many.

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<EventUsers> EventUsers { get; set; } // This is table that holds EventId, UserId (many2many)
    public IQueryable<User> Users { get { return this.EventUsers.Select(x => x.User); } } // Get all users that are in this event
}
```

Comment: If you don't have additional properties on the join table, I don't think it's typical to have a model for the join table itself.  Typically, you would just connect Events to Users directly via collections.

Comment: @tvanfosson You mean let EF create the table and so you don't even have to? I did this once and it turned out badly because queries EF were making were `N+1` so I stick with mapping Models2DB 1 to 1 to have more control. Hence `IQueryable` and not `List`.

Comment: No, use OnModelCreating to directly map between User and Event via the table, but not expose the join table directly in the model. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First