# how to create this query with lambda expression or query expression?

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I have this tables:

- TableA(IDTableA, ...)
- TableAC(IDTableA, IDTableC)
- TableC(IDtableC...)

I have the entities TableA y TableC but not for the TableB. In the entity TableA I have a collection ICOllection and in the tableC I have a collection Icollection.

I would like to get all the registers in TableA that has registers in TableC which TableC has a ID = 5.

In T-SQL whould be:

```
select * from TableA, TableAC, TableC
where TableA.IDTableA = TableAC.IDTableA
and TableC.IDTableC = TableAC.IDTableB
and TableA.IDTable = 5;
```

How can I do this query with lambda expressions? Syntax query is another option too.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Many to Many query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419497/entity-framework-many-to-many-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the entity framework omits the relation table AC when generating the entites, and instead generates and populates the ICollection properties. In essence it makes the many-2-many relation invisible. To get all entities from TableA which has a relation to TableC = 5, you can directly make a LINQ query to this ICollection:

```
from ta in TableA
where ta.TableC.Any(tc => tc.Id == 5)
select ta;
```

UPDATE:
As Tough Coder mentioned - LINQPad truly is your friend when it comes to testing linq queries. Not to mention that is invaluable as a code scratchpad (just testing small samples without firing up a completely new VS project). I just made a complete sample to illustrate the entity relation and linq query you need:

```
void Main()
{
    List<TableA> ta = new List<TableA>();

    var ta1 = new TableA() { Id = 1 };
    var ta2 = new TableA() { Id = 2 };
    var ta3 = new TableA() { Id = 3 };

    ta.Add(ta1);
    ta.Add(ta2);
    ta.Add(ta3);

    var tc1 = new TableC() { Id = 1 };
    var tc2 = new TableC() { Id = 2 };
    var tc3 = new TableC() { Id = 3 };

    ta1.TableCs.Add(tc1);
    ta1.TableCs.Add(tc3);

    ta2.TableCs.Add(tc1);

    ta3.TableCs.Add(tc2);
    ta3.TableCs.Add(tc3);

    var res = from t in ta
              where t.TableCs.Any(tc => tc.Id == 3)
              select t.Id;

    foreach (var t in res)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}

public class TableA
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<TableC> TableCs{get;set;}
    public TableA()
    {
        TableCs = new List<TableC>();
    }
}

public class TableC
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<TableA> TableAs{get;set;}
    public TableC()
    {
        TableAs = new List<TableA>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a long way you can do this:

```
from c in db.TableA
where c.TableC.Any(tc => tc.Id == 5)
select c;
```

If you want to check this code in SQL, You can use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It will show this Linq query in SQL.

For another solution you might just send your SQL query by using ExecuteStoreQuery. Such as:

```
db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Results_Class>("select * from TableA, TableAC, TableC
where TableA.IDTableA = TableAC.IDTableA
and TableC.IDTableC = TableAC.IDTableB
and TableA.IDTable = 5;");
```

For this solution you have to create a Results_Class class.

Comment: My problem it's that I don't have the table TableAC in EF becase EF does not create the entity for this kind of tables.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Entity framework omits the M2M table and populates the ICollection properties instead. You can make the linq query into this instead - check my answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía I read your question too quickly. You can check my answer again.